# Copy Mat data to another Mat

Tags: c++, opencv

I need to copy my image data from one Mat another Mat. My code look like below

```
Mat src; // Source image
Mat res(1024,768,CV_8UC3); //Same width and height as source
uchar *dest=src.data;
res.data=dest;
```

But I am getting distorted destination image. Is it my coding problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But I am getting distorted destination image. Is it my coding problem?

If width and height is the same than it seems that problem is with number of channels (number of bytes per pixel). Try to change `CV_8UC3` to `CV_8UC1`.

And also your code doesn't copy *data*, it copies *pointers*. Read documentation about [`memcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/).

Actually you should use method `clone` of [`cv::Mat`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html#mat):

```
// returns deep copy of the matrix, i.e. the data is copied
    Mat clone() const;
```

Comment: So the above code is wrong ? Actually I need to copy Mat.data to a pointer.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. Actually my Mat width and height were in reverse order that's why I got distorted image any way I solved it.

Comment: Hi I have one more doubt. Is it possible to assign Mat pointer to another pointer. Like uchar *p= Mat B.

Comment: You can assign any pointer to any pointer. Pointer - it's just address (number). But it makes no sense. You should use `c++` features, not `c`. You'd better read some c++ books before asking such questions: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/